# How to break the loop if webelement value matches to excel value

Tags: java

I am using application which has 19 pages. on each page there are 10 accounts and 10 checkboxes in front of them.

I have kept a list of some accounts in excel sheet and want to read account number in excel one by one, match it with accounts on webpage, if value matched->set the checkbox in front of that account and move for the next account in excel.....and this way repeat till last account is matched in excel list.

If account is not matched with any of the 10 accounts on webpage, i need to click on next arrow(present below account list on webpage) and check if account number matches with any of the account on new webpage.

code is as below

```
    String data=null; //to get value of account on webpage
    int count=0;
    do{
    for(count=0;count<=9;count++)
    {
        data= (String) al1.get(count);  //al1=List of accounts on webelement 
        if(stg.equals(data))        //stg=account read from execl
        {
            utl.checkbox_clicking(data);//calling method to set checkbox if                value matches
            break;
        }
    }

    utl.Weblement_Click("*name of weblement of next page arrow*");
    al1 = utl.Account_List();   //loading new account list on next page in List
    }while(stg.equals(data));
```

There is some problem in logic. Can somebody suggest the what changes i should make?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that your problem is when you find what you need you just execute break. But break go just out the inner loop, and not the outer.

So without trying to change anything in your code and reorganize something I want to tell that there is something unused in java, maybe because of unreadability of the code, that called labeled block. Maybe one of the only uses of it is to break out of outer loops. I hope it will help you and it's the right solution for your problem.
Note that most of the time if you find yourself using it maybe you need to change your loop. In your case I would go with something like while loop with two conditions: one for 10 account in each page and one when you can't find more pages.

here's a short tutorial about that:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html

So in your code I just added the the first statement and the break line.

```
pagesLoop:
        do {
            for (count = 0; count <= 9; count++) {
                data = (String) al1.get(count);  //al1=List of accounts on webelement
                if (stg.equals(data))        //stg=account read from execl
                {
                    utl.checkbox_clicking(data);//calling method to set checkbox if                value matches
                    break pagesLoop;
                }
            }

            utl.Weblement_Click("*name of weblement of next page arrow*");
            al1 = utl.Account_List();   //loading new account list on next page in List
        } while (stg.equals(data));
```

Comment: I could see that loopbraking is done as desired. Thank you for that:).......but  when clicked on next page arrorw, arraylist is not loaded with new 10 accounts on new webpage.

            utl.Weblement_Click("*name of weblement of next page arrow*");
            al1 = utl.Account_List();

I tried implimenting wait statement after clicking on arrow, but it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Removing unnecessary loop and also missed count should be `count<9` instead of count<=9

```
 for(int count=0;count<9;count++) {
           String data = (String) al1.get(count);  //al1=List of accounts on webelement 
            if(stg.equals(data))        //stg=account read from execl
            {
                utl.checkbox_clicking(data);//calling method to set checkbox if                value matches
                break;
            }
}

utl.Weblement_Click("*name of weblement of next page arrow*");
al1 = utl.Account_List();   //loading new account list on next page in List
```